# Writing an Action Invoker - How can I call a method on user choice?

Tags: c#, algorithm, function, methods, multiple-choice

as you can see in my code, I want to hold( set ) a method into an object.
And call the method with that object...

Please take look at the code, you can understand easly; 
it's hard to explain in plain English...

My question is; Ofcourse "Action operation" object can't hold the method that will be called.

So, how can I solve this problem? What can I do?

```
...
    enum CampaignUserChoice
    {
        Insert,
        Update,
        Delete,
        Disable
    }
```

private void AskUserAboutCampaignOperation(CampaignUserChoice choice)
    {
        string questionForUser = string.Empty;
        string questionTitleForUser = string.Empty;
        Action operation; //<<<<--------------------- this line, it's method holder

        if (choice == CampaignUserChoice.Insert)
        {
            questionForUser = "Do you want to create a new campaign?";
            questionTitleForUser = "NEW CAMPAIGN";
            operation = InsertCampaign(TakeDatasFromGui()); //<---------- set which method you want to call 
        }
        else
        {
            operation = UpdateCampaign( campaignId, TakeDatasFromGui()); 
        }
        //TODO write other elses...

        switch (MessageBox.Show(questionForUser, questionTitleForUser, MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question))
        {
            case DialogResult.Yes:
                operation; //<<<------------------ call method here...
                break;

            case DialogResult.No:
                // "No" processing
                break;

            case DialogResult.Cancel:
                // "Cancel" processing
                break;
        }
    }

Thank you very much for all answers...

Comment: You don't have an object here, I really don't understand what you want.  Do you want to have a method saved to an object so that when you call the method it does something with/to that object?

Comment: Yes, I want to have a method saved to an object so that way I can call the object to invoke the method. Sorry for my terrible english...

Comment: I think what SLaks answered below is what you want.  But if you are looking more for what I described that is pretty easy too, but I think SLaks is right, try delegates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use [**delegates**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx):

```
operation = TakeDataFromGui;
...
operation();
```

Answer (score 1):

use a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) to assign the delegate:

```
operation = () => InsertCampaign(TakeDatasFromGui());
```

invoke the action like a regular function:

```
operation()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need  [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) to call method

```
  //declare delegate declaration same as function
   delegate returntype delegate_name(parameter1,paramenter2,..);

   //assaign function to  delegate
   delegate_name=function();

   //call function
   delagate_name();
```